# Compactness of covering space

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, covering-spaces

If we have space $X$ with and $n$ sheeted covering space $Y$ is $Y$ compact iff $X$ is?

Torus or sphere, make me believe the answer is yes.

Comment: Yes. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/32111/compactness-and-covering-spaces

Comment: In fact, $Y$ compact implies $X$ compact for any covering space $Y$ over $X$, and if $X$ is compact, then $Y$ is compact iff the fibers are finite.